# not able to run hbase shell command

Tags: hbase

i am trying to run hbase shell command, but getting follwing error
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1000m "
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
please tell the solution

Comment: Can you try this command and check output. check what is heap size configured for you machine.   java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize'

Comment: it is showing the filename,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize'   <<<< is this the command that you run?

Comment: yaa..  i am running same command.. where to run this command? in c drive??

Comment: are you using windows machine for hbase?